# emulator or Physical device is better when we develop apps

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter, dart

I want to know, when it comes to app development, emulators, or physical devices is recommended? when I tried with emulators it's slow compared to the physical device and consuming a lot of system resources.

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you want your app to work on a variety of devices you should use emulator to simulate as many as possible, if it's just for your own personal use, a physical device might be better. There is no real difference other than convenience..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a specific answer to this question but based on my experience

- If you have Low Performance PC/Laptop then **Use Physical Device**
- If you are using 3rd party plugins, features like sending `SMS` or using `Location` or any other feature that may require actual usage of mobile device then its better to use physical device.

Other than this, emulator will do quite a job.
Cheer :)